# Load balance data coming from AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-sqs

I have multiple instances in ElasticBeanstalk which have worker tier. The instance poll data using the SQS Daemon from a single SQS queue. In production, I observe, the load is not being balanced and only 2-3 instances get the load, resulting in degradation. How can I balance this load effectively?

PS: The load balancer is setup and short polling is also configured.

Answer (score 3):

A **load balancer** is not used when workers pull messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

It is possible that there aren't enough messages for all workers, or workers are pulling multiple messages (and not leaving enough for other workers). Try grabbing only **single messages** and see if it improves.

It is also possible that **long polling** would be more effective since the `ReceiveMessages()` request will wait until a message is available, or 20 seconds elapses. Give it a try.